# NameError: global name 'form' is not defined. Flask-MySQL

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

i'm new in Python and Flask. I try to create a website where you can add books and write them into a MySQL-database. When I run my Project with PyCharm it works fine until I navigate to the site where I would like to add my books. 
**The Error says: NameError: global name 'form' is not defined.**
Can someone please help me to fix this? Maybe I write the code at the wrong place, I dont know.

My Code is:

**views.py:**

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, session, url_for, request
from flask.ext.login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, login_required
from app import app, db, mysql
from .forms import LoginForm, AddForm, RegForm
from .models import User

@app.route('/books/add/admin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def books_add_admin():
    add = AddForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
             '''
             cursor = mysql.get_db().cursor()
             author = request.args.get(form.author.data)
             '''
        test = request.args.get(form.title.data)
        author = request.args.get(form.author.data)
        verlag = request.args.get(form.publisher.data)
        isbn = request.args.get(form.isbn.data)
        auflage = request.args.get(form.edition.data)
        exemplare = request.args.get(form.copies.data)
        kurztext = request.args.get(form.short_text.data)
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO books (Titel, Autor, Verlag, ISBN, Auflage, Info)
        VALUES (titel, author, verlag, isbn, auflage, info);")

             #cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
        con.commit()
        curser.close()
```

**And the code of the forms.py:**

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField, BooleanField, PasswordField, validators,
TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length


class LoginForm(Form):
    student_number = IntegerField('student_number', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    #remember_me = BooleanField('remember_me', default=False)

class AddForm(Form):
    title = StringField('title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    author = StringField('author', validators=[DataRequired()])
    publisher = StringField('publisher', validators=[DataRequired()])
    isbn = IntegerField('isbn', validators=[Length(min=10, max=13)])
    edition = IntegerField('edition', validators=[Length(min=1, max=3)])
    copies = IntegerField('copies', validators=[Length(min=1, max=3)])
    short_info = TextAreaField('short_info', validators=[Length(min=0, max=1040)])

class RegForm(Form):
    student_number = IntegerField('student_number', validators=[Length(min=6, max=7)])
    forname = StringField('forname', validators=[DataRequired()])
    surname = StringField('surname', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('email', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[Length(min=6, max=24)])
    password2 = PasswordField('password2', validators=[Length(min=6, max=24)])
```

Comment: I don't think `test = request.args.get(form.title.data)` is what you want. `request.args` is a `MultiDict` that contains key-value pairs from the query string. `form.title.data` contains the value from the form's `title` field. `I think you just want `test = form.title.data`.

Comment: I've changed it as you say. It is the better solution. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be the issue:

```
add = AddForm()
```

You named your variable `add`, whereas you are attemping to reference the variable `form` here:

```
test = request.args.get(form.title.data)
author = request.args.get(form.author.data)
verlag = request.args.get(form.publisher.data)
isbn = request.args.get(form.isbn.data)
auflage = request.args.get(form.edition.data)
exemplare = request.args.get(form.copies.data)
```

The easiest solution would to rename your variable:

```
form = AddForm()
```

Comment: Yes, the variable name is wrong, but I would think he would be better off using request.form.get('title') or test = form.title.data

Comment: works, thank you! But now i get an commit() error. "NameError: global name 'conn' is not defined". Did you have an Idea?

Comment: @kynie it looks like it's a similar issue. You have the line "con.execute()", but you are not defining "con" anywhere in your code. You are trying to do a method call on something that does not exist

Answer (score 3):

In views.py, try changing:

```
add = AddForm()
```

To

```
form = AddForm()
```